# Cron job breaks the code output on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, cron

I'm running Node.js code below on Amazon Linux 2 (EC2). When the code runs on my local computer (Mac) and runs on EC2 triggered by Command Line (e.g.`node index.js`) or sh file, it works totally fine. But only when the code runs triggered by Cron on EC2, the data is lost somewhere. I have no idea what's going on. Beside, I can't debug the code using console.log statements because console.log inside `runB.js` has no output even though using redirecting in sh-file (crontab: ***** /path/to/x.sh > /path/to/y.log 2>&1). Any ideas?

````
const doA = async(item) => {
    const res = spawnSync('node runB.js 'arg'', [], {shell: true})
    console.log(res.stdout.toString()) // empty value is returned with Cron job, but I need the value!

}

const main = () => {
    for(let item of items){
    await doA(item)
}
}

---- main ends ----

---- runB.js ----

const doC = async(item) => {

    someAPICall()

    anotherAPIcall()

    const res = another API call etc
    await outputToCsv(res)
    return true
}

const data = process.argv.pop()
const item = JSON.parse(data)

const main = () => {
    if(await doC(item)){
     process.kill()
     return
    } else {
        return 'whatever'
    }

}
--- runB.js ends ----```
````

Comment: By default, cron jobs run as the root user.